# torch.sub cause cuda memory out

Tags: pytorch, tensor, torch, computation

I have two tensors, `a` and `b`, with sizes `a.shape=(10000,10000,120)` and `b.shape=(10000,10000,120)`.

I'm trying to get a cost matrix between `a` and `b`,
`cost = torch.sub((a-b)**2,-1)`, where `cost.shape=(10000,10000)`.

The problem is, when I tried to do `a-b` or `torch.sum(a,b,alpha=1)`, a "CUDA MEMORY OUT" error occurs.

I don't think it should cost that much. It works when the size of the tensor is small, like 2000.

Using a `for` iteration is not an efficient way. How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It does costs much (about 134 GB).**

Let's do some calculations.

Assuming your data is of type `torch.float32`, `a` will occupy a memory size of:

32 bits (4 Bytes) * 10000 * 10000 * 120 = 4.8E10 bytes ≈ 44.7 G Bytes

So does `b`. When you do `b-a`, the result also has the same shape with `a` and thus occupies the same amount of memory, which means you need a total of 44.7 GB * 3 (≈ 134 GB) memory to do this operation.

Is your available memory size greater than 134GB?

**Possible solution:**

If you will no longer use `a` or `b` afterwards, you can store the result in one of them to prevents to allocating another 44.7 GB space like this:

```py
torch.sub(a, b, out=a)  # In this case, the result goes to `a`
```

Comment: Now I understood the problem, but couldn't solve it. I decided to calculate it several times with mini-batch.